# Opening url with schema appended in new window Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, window

I have the URL of an uploaded file like this,

"http://localhost/App/uploads/image1.png"

I need to append the string "pic.scheme://" at the beginning of this url and open in new window.

When I try to open this in new window, missing the **:** from "pic.scheme://" in the address bar.

**What I need is:**
    "pic.scheme://http://localhost/App/uploads/image1.png"

**What am getting is:** "pic.scheme//http://localhost/App/uploads/image1.png"